# How does tipping Moxxi work?

Tags: borderlands-2

According to the [Borderlands Wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Sanctuary#Moxxi.27s):

> Cumulatively large contributions to Moxxi's tip jar will result in gifts to the Vault Hunter.

I only found this out after giving her about $1,200 (1x $1,000 & 2x $100) just for the sake of seeing what would happen. Aside from some amusing commentary, I got nothing.

So, how does this work?

- What are the thresholds at which she starts giving loot - are they set points, or is she effectively another slot machine?
- Does the "cumulative" donation need to be given in one visit, or can it be spread out across multiple stops in the zone?
- Are there any particular items that she gives, or is it just random leveled loot approximate in value to the donation level?
- Is the loot even worth it - could I sell the given loot and get anywhere close to a full return on my investment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Mad_Moxxi#Items), Moxi will give you the weapon [Bad Touch](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Bad_Touch), a corrosive SMG, after you have given her 10,000-20,000 dollars. The weapon [Good Touch](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Good_Touch), an incendiary SMG, will be given when you have tipped her 20,000-50,000 dollars.
Both weapons may have further additonal randomized values.
These two guns are the only two things Moxi will give you when tipping her.
Considering the amount of money you get from one gun, you can calculate the monetary gain (or loss more likely).
The amount you tip her is also cumulative within the same playthrough.
After Moxi has given you a gun you must leave Sanctuary to be given another reward for tipping her, as continuing to give her money before you revisit the area will only result in you losing money.

Comment: I knew there *had* to be something I'd missed in the Wiki. Thanks.

Comment: I have found it impossible to get her to give me the bad touch in UVHM. I would love a lv 61 Bad Touch, but after trying 100+ times and only getting the Good Touch I gave up.

Comment: Additionally, I have tested the wiki's info and it does not hold up to experimentation. I have recieved many of the fire smg (good touch) in every playthrough for anywhere from $200 to $400,000 and of the three times i have recieved the caustic (bad touch) i have paid less than 10,000 for two and over 40,000 for the third. It appears to be completely random, with the one certainty being that you will not get a caustic (bad touch) if you are in playthrough 3 (UVHM)